# Django aggregate with expressions between ForeignKey (and not) values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having these models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
  liter_per_km = models.FloatField(default=1.0)
  
class DrivingSession(models.Model):
  car = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  km = models.FloatField(default=1.0)
```

Is there a way using Django features (e.g aggregate) to calculate the same `total_liters` like in code below?

```
total_liters = 0.0
for session in DrivingSession.objects.all():
  total_liters += (session.km * session.car.liter_per_km)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

DrivingSession.objects.aggregate(
    total_liters=Sum(F('car__liter_per_km') * F('km'))
)
```

This will thus multiple the number of kilometers of that `DrivingSession` with the `liter_per_km` for that `car`.